# How to remove 'text' in public pages in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Anybody knows how to remove 'text' section in public pages in Word Press?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T5x2.png)

Comment: You have used any plugin for public pages?

Comment: Yes but i could not change 'text' in code because its marked as required.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it's a plugin. May be in plugin configuration?
Otherwise you have to edit the plugin.

Also, there are some options, called screen options (in the top right corner) where you can enable/disable some options that are not required.

But as I see - there is a red asterisk for the text, so this is required option.

Comment: i also did try screen options but if i disable that then picture also will dissappear. It is required and i could not remove it.

Comment: So the only way is to edit the plugin source files. Or configure it, if it provides any configuration for that.